# Consent on a per-cookie or cookie-provider basis or per category?

Tags: privacy, consent

As title mentioned: I am wondering about requirements regarding the need to enable users/visitors of a website to consent on a per-cookie or cookie category (e.g. analytical, personalization etc) basis under EU law.

Question 1: Simply put: is it allowed to only allow a user to give/deny consent on a category of cookies (and with that, all cookies that fall within that category), or do you need to provide the option to give/deny consent on a per-cookie basis?

Question 2: In addition to this: if a user consents to a category of cookies (e.g. marketing), is it allowed to make changes to cookies in that category under that consent? In other words: if I were to consent to marketing cookies, can a website add marketing cookies later assuming I've consented to this category, and therefore also these newly added cookies?

I cannot find any specific requirements in the E-privacy directive or local implementation thereof (although I have gotten references to S25 of TTDSG, but this is broadly defined to say the very least).

There is arguments to make for both sides, mostly depending on the (extend of) the interpretation of the principles of 'informed' or 'specific' consent.

That said, I cannot find too much information. There is guidance on this from both the British and Italian DPA on this, though these guidelines date from 2012 and 2014 respectively.

Any input is highly appreciated, in particular substantiated with legal sources.

Comment: the old guidance is still relevant because the "cookie law" (amended ePrivacy Directive) is from 2009. The 2016 GDPR only changed the definition of "consent". Consent must be specific for a *purpose*. The EDPB has written guidelines on consent and the various aspects thereof. TTDSG is just a very late German implementation of ePrivacy, its § 26 (consent management services) is irrelevant in practice and § 25 is just a rephrasing of ePrivacy. For marketing cookie consent, you should also consider industry best practices such as the IAB consent framework (but that's an marketing industry group).